# Short story called "Idiot planet" or something similar

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telepathy

Short story about a multi-species team which is composed of humans and some other alien species sent to study an amphibian sentient species which suffers a pandemic that damages their gills. Aliens in the human team are telepathic.

Comment: Why the downvote for "unclear"? The story identification tag makes clear that I'm asking for title and author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly Phyllis Gotlieb's novelette "[Planetoid Idiot](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53830)" (1967), which, as helpfully noted by user14111, [can be read in its entirety online](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v032n05_1967-05_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v032n05_1967-05_PDF#page/n1) courtesy of archive.org.

The first few paragraphs of the story refer to the gill disease issue:

> It was past midnight at the GalFed Observer station on Xirifor II;
> mist swirled over the waters, and the huge float, which housed all
> Galactic Federation business on the planet, was tugging gently at its
> moorings. Ripples moved in silence against the timbers under the cool
> night winds. Inside, in the tank room, a hand turned up the cock on
> Vavvingru's sleeping tank and he quietly began to drown.
>
> Water poured between the **flared leaves of his lungbook**, but he did
> not waken; although **he had lost his external gills from disease**,
> what was left of his internal system extracted the mixture of
> available gases he called air for half an hour; then it became
> overloaded, and he started choking.

Telepathy is mentioned in a passage soon afterward:

> Across the room, in a larger tank full of the waters of a different
> planet, Hrufa stirred in her sleep and woke. **Without having to open
> her eyes, she knew everything in less than a second**...
>
> **She began to broadcast powerful impulses**, soundless wordless siren
> blasts. If they had been audible, they would have shattered eardrums
> and perhaps skulls...
>
> ... the **tp waves** knocked the Solthrees out of their bunks...

I did also find an excerpt from a discussion about it via [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=tp7UBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22planetoid%20idiot%22&source=bl&ots=kF5ORd88cH&sig=5fH3evpvXCjM4_B8IAa2WqHRvjY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPk-2Al9POAhUBeSYKHS4uCo0Q6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22planetoid%20idiot%22&f=false):

> It is better to believe, and probably the truth, that GalFed would
> have come to the aid of the Xirifri even if the survey ship had not
> discovered that the seas of Xirifor produced oysters that secreted
> pearls, huge, baroque and blue, more beautiful than any known before.
> Whatever the truth was, the pearls at least gave the peoples of the
> planet something to bargain with.

Hopefully, those names sound familiar.